# Better way to turn a ruby class into a module than using refinements?

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.0, refinements

[`Module#refine`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-refine) method takes a class and a block and returns a refinement module, so I thought I could define:

```
class Class
  def include_refined(klass)
    _refinement = Module.new do
      include refine(klass) {
        yield if block_given?
      }
    end
    self.send :include, _refinement
  end
end
```

and the following test passes

```
class Base
  def foo
    "foo"
  end
end

class Receiver
  include_refined(Base) {
    def foo
      "refined " + super
    end
  }
end

describe Receiver do
  it { should respond_to(:foo) }
  its(:foo) { should eq("refined foo") }
end
```

So, using refinements, I can turn a class into a module, refine its behaviour on the fly, and include it in other classes.

- Is there a simpler way to turn a class into a module in Ruby (say in ruby < 2)?
- In the C-implementation of [rb_mod_refine](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/1c7f9073b018319fbea5ffe98d7264d4553aaec1/eval.c#L1196)
  we see

  ```
  refinement = rb_module_new();
  RCLASS_SET_SUPER(refinement, klass);
  ```

  Is this just setting the superclass of refinement to `klass` that copies the implementation of the class inside the refinement module?
- I am aware that multiple inheritance IS
  done via Modules, but what would the community think of the above `Class#include_refined`?
  Would it be reasonable to extract this aspect out of refinements?
  "Locally" patching inside a Class instead of using "using" switches to activate refinements?

Comment: Sounds like an unusual solution. Is there any practical use cases in Rails?

Comment: @BillyChan Imagine I want to use all actions defined in some controller class defined in some gem (or Rails::Engine) in my controller, which of course inherits from my `ApplicationController`. Take [Tolk::LocalesController](https://github.com/tolk/tolk/blob/master/app/controllers/tolk/locales_controller.rb) for instance.

Comment: I'm confused as to why you would want to do this. Why not define it as a module, and if you need to instantiate something with _just those methods_ you can create a class that does nothing but include the modules.

Comment: Why would you not just inherit from the controller class inside of that gem?

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23945393/rails-engines-rendered-view and

Comment: A class is a subclass of a module so to me trying to make it back into its parent seems over complicated. Your original problem statement to me seems to be the exact use case of a module vs class

Comment: There’s a very good article about this: https://www.new-bamboo.co.uk/blog/2014/02/05/refinements-under-the-knife/.

Answer (score 4):

I am happy indeed with Ruby 2.1 (and later) class-level "private" scope of refinements. My example above can be rephrased as:

```
# spec/modulify_spec.rb
module Modulify
  refine(Class) do
    def include_refined(klass)
      _refined = Module.new do
        include refine(klass) { yield if block_given? }
      end
      include _refined
    end
  end
end

class A
  def a
    "I am an 'a'"
  end
end

class B
  using Modulify

  include_refined(A) do
    def a
      super + " and not a 'b'"
    end
  end

  def b
    "I cannot say: " + a
  end
end

RSpec.describe B do
  it "can use refined methods from A" do
    expect(subject.b).to eq "I cannot say: I am an 'a' and not a 'b'"
  end
end
```

and suits as solution for the original problem.

Answer (score 1):

Andrea, thank you for the info in comment. Excuse my lack of knowledge to understand this is really necessary though it sounds doable as per your research.

I don't think we need to go so low level to do something in Rails.

If I'm going to do similar on Engine, I will try the following ideas, from easy to hard.

1. In routes.rb, mount the whole engine in right route.

   *I'm afraid this most common usage can't fit your need*
2. In routes.rb, Customize engine's route for specific controllers in application route.

   *Devise, as an engine, can do easily. But I know not every engine could do this*.
3. In routes.rb, redirect specific or whole set of routes to engine's routes
4. In your application's action, redirect to specific engine's action in application's action.

   *This should be customized enough for specific action*

   ```
   class FoosController < ApplicationController
     def foo
       redirect_to some_engine_path if params[:foo] == 'bar'
     end
   ```
5. Inherit the engine's controller - for a set of actions, and if all above can't fit

   *The engine's classes are available in all application, you can inherit a controller from them, instead of normal ApplicationController.

   ```
   # class FoosController < ApplicationController
   class FoosController < BarEngine::BarsController
   ```

   *Since most engine's controller inherit from ApplicationController, this inheritance still allows you to use your own things from ApplicationController, no bad effect at all.
6. If all above can't do, I can try to serve a customized locally or from my github repo.

In conclusion, the above should be able to solve most of cases, and I myself prefer #5 when possible and needed.

Comment: thanks for the answer but I didn't really mean to start a thread about rails. By the way, I would also prefer 5. As you point out 'most' engines controller (see Devise) inherit from `ApplicationController` but `Tolk::ApplicationController` (which I mention above) doesn't.