# Ruby refinements subtleties

Tags: ruby, refinements

There is a pretty good documentation of the current implementation of refinements in ruby here:
http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html,
but there are some strange corner cases.

First, `include module` is orthogonal to `using module` (one include the instance method of module while the other activates the refinement). But there is a trick to include a refinement module itself, see
[Better way to turn a ruby class into a module than using refinements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551058/better-way-to-turn-a-ruby-class-into-a-module-than-using-refinements).

```
def to_module(klass)
  Module.new do
    #note that we return the refinement module itself here
    return refine(klass) {
      yield if block_given?
    }
  end
end

class Base
  def foo
    "foo"
  end
end
class Receiver
  include to_module(Base) {
    def foo
      "refined " + super
    end
  }
end
Receiver.new.foo #=> "refined foo"
```

Strangely this refinement module can't be used with `using`!

```
m=to_module(Base) {}
m.class #=> Module
using m    
#=>TypeError: wrong argument type Class (expected Module)
```

So using only work on the enclosing module of the refinement modules.
Secondly I wanted to use the above yield trick to be able to pass a Proc to refine (even through it only accepts a block), without resorting to converting the Proc back to source as in
https://www.new-bamboo.co.uk/blog/2014/02/05/refinements-under-the-knife/.
But using `yield` as in the include example does not work:

```
def ref_module1(klass)
  Module.new do
    refine(klass) {
      yield
    }
  end
end

class Receiver1
  using ref_module1(Base) {
    def foo
      "refined " + super
    end
  }
  def bar
    Base.new.foo
  end
end
Receiver1.new.bar #=> NoMethodError: super: no superclass method `foo'
```

We see that Receiver1 still use Bar#foo and not the refined method.
Howewer we can use `module_eval` instead:

```
def ref_module2(klass,&b)
  Module.new do
    refine(klass) {
      module_eval(&b)
    }
  end
end

class Receiver2
  using ref_module2(Base) {
    def foo
      "refined " + super
    end
  }
  def bar
    Base.new.foo
  end
end
Receiver2.new.bar #=> "refined foo"
```

I don't quite understand why `module_eval` works here and not the `yield` method. Inside the refinement block, the 'default_definee' is the refinement module, so `module_eval` which puts the 'default_definee' to `self`='the refinement module' should not affect it. And indeed in the 'include' example at the beginning, I get the same result when I use `module_eval` or a direct `yield`.

Can anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: Great question. I hope you get some equally-great answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Context (or binding) is the reason why module_eval works and yield doesn't in your last set of examples. It actually has nothing to do with refinements, as demonstrated below.

Starting with `module_eval`:

```
class Foo
  def run(&block)
    self.class.module_eval(&block)
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.run {
  def hello
    "hello"
  end
}

puts foo.hello # => "hello"
puts hello => # '<main>': undefined method 'hello' for main:Object (NameError)
```

In `Foo#run` we call `module_eval` on `Foo`. This switches the context (`self`) to be `Foo`. The result is much like we had simple defined `hello` inside of `class Foo` originally.

Now let's take a look at `yield`:

```
class Foo
  def run
    yield
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.run {
  def hello
    "hello"
  end
}

puts hello # => "hello"
puts foo.hello # => '<main>': private method 'hello' called for ...
```

`yield` simply invokes the block in its original context, which in this example would be `<main>`. When the block is invoked, the end result is exactly the same as if the method were defined at the top level normally:

```
class Foo
  def run
    yield
  end
end

foo = Foo.new

def hello
  "hello"
end

puts hello # => "hello"
puts foo.hello # => '<main>': private method 'hello' called for ...
```

You might notice that `foo` seems to have the `hello` method in the `yield` examples. This is a side effect of defining `hello` as a method at the top level. It turns out that `<main>` is just an instance of `Object`, and defining top level methods is really just defining private methods on `Object` which nearly everything else ends up inheriting. You can see this by opening up irb and running the following:

```
self       # => main
self.class # => Object

def some_method
end

"string".method(:some_method) # => #<Method: String(Object)#some_method>
```

Now back to your examples.

Here's what happens in the `yield` example:

```
def ref_module1(klass)
  Module.new do
    refine(klass) {
      yield
    }
  end
end

class Receiver1
  # like my yield example, this block is going to
  # end up being invoked in its original context
  using ref_module1(Base) {
    def foo
      "I'm defined on Receiver1"
    end
  }

  def bar
    # calling foo here will simply call the original
    # Base#foo method
    Base.new.foo
  end
end

# as expected, if we call Receiver1#bar
# we get the original Base#foo method
Receiver1.new.bar # => "foo"

# since the block is executed in its original context
# the method gets defined in Receiver1 -- its original context
Receiver1.new.foo # => "I'm defined on Receiver1"
```

As for `module_eval`, it works in your examples because it causes the block to be run in the context of the new module, rather than on the `Receiver1` class.

Comment: You are right, since the block is a closure it will contains the current values of 'self' and 'klass' so we need to use module_eval to set 'klass' to the anonymous module. I was confused by the fact that the first example was working, but actually 'foo' is defined on Receiver and not on the anonymous module as I thought. Thanks!